# By using useNavigate() function, I am getting this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using useNavigate and this error is coming:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

The code is following:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Recipeitem() {

  let navigate = useNavigate;
  const gotoRecipes = ()=>{
    navigate(`/recipe`);
  }

  return (
      <button onClick={()=>{gotoRecipes()}}>Go to Page</button>
  );
}
```

I have tried many solutions but doesn't work. Please help.
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: `let navigate = useNavigate();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useNavigate is a react hook (function) not a value. You have to call it with `()`.

```
let navigate = useNavigate();
```

Comment: Sorry! what a silly mistake I made.